# Android server data fetch

Tags: android

I want to fetch some data from a server protected with an username and password . I know both the username and password . Since the server is live , the data is continuing changing I need to fetch data every minute to update the application's status . The only function I know that can fetch data and turn it to a string is :

```
private String getPage() {
            String str = "***";

            try
            {
                HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.me");
                HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

                if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {
                    str = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

            return str;
        }
```

Since the server has a logon screen I don't know how to get pass it . So , i'd like help with 2 thigs :**1.** getting the data from the server and **2.** every 1 or 2 minutes I need to refresh my app and fetch again the data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for the post object. Pre-emptive authentication is done this way.

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // Prepare the authentication.
    String usernameAuth = "u";
    String passwordAuth = "p";
    post.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + 
            Base64.encodeToString((usernameAuth + ":" + passwordAuth).getBytes("UTF-8"),
                android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

For running this at regular intervals :

```
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
       // What you want to do goes here
     }
  }, 0, REFRESH_TIME);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: instead of REFRESH_TIME I put the time in milliseconds or seconds or how do I insert the refresh time ?